# GEE: Reduce region function is not producing all properties for all features

Tags: google-earth-engine, tile-reduce

I have a feature collection of sub-districts in sub-Saharan Africa:

```
var Africa = ee.FeatureCollection
('users/salem043/Africa_Districts').select("ADM3");
```

I'm also using the Global Forest Change data:

```
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015').clip(Africa);
```

I am trying to produce annual estimates of square meters of forest cover loss by subdistrict. The following code worked when I did this for countries, not subdistricts:

```
//Identifies the year in which the pixel transitioned
var lossYear = gfc2014.select(['lossyear']);

var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossYear) 
  .reduceRegions({ 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({groupField: 1}),
  collection: Africa, 
  scale: 30
});


var addGroups = function(feature) {
  var statsFormatted = ee.List(feature.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
  });
  var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());

  return feature.set(statsDictionary);
};

print("Final forest loss df", lossByYear.map(addGroups).limit(10))
lossByYear = lossByYear.map(addGroups)
```

But when I run it for the subdistricts, there are many missing observations. The code should produce thirteen new variables for each subdistrict: forest loss in 2001, 2002, 2003, ...2014. But the number of new variables produced varies across sub-districts! For some, only a few year variables are produced, while for others, we're a lot closer to having a complete panel.

Is this a missing data issue? Should I assume forest loss is zero in those years for those subdistricts where no variable is produced?

Moreover, when I exported this data, only two year forest loss variables exported: 2013 and 2014.

Code in GEE is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f80c17a94a5bcdd295cb5a8c122d1dcf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exporting, GEE will sample the properties present for the first feature and will only export that properties (except system properties). You can manually change the properties in the `selectors` argument of `Export.table.toDrive`. If you print the first feature, you will see the properties present:

```
print(lossByYear.first().propertyNames())
```

For you case, when there would be no forest loss, I guess the loss of area in that year should be 0. Subsequently, I think it is most straightforward to first make a featureCollection `Africa` with all properties set to zero. Then apply you function and years with forest loss will be overwritten:

```
// preset all properties to 0
var keys = ee.List.sequence(0,14,1).map(function(year){
  return ee.Number(year).format("20%02d");
});
var preSetPropsAfrica = Africa.map(function(feat){
  return feat.set(ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys,ee.List.repeat(0,15)));
});
```

Now run with this featureCollection exactly what you did and all properties in all feature will have a value. Printing a subset seems to work, please let me know if exporting works for you! [Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4c14dc209360aa2e44cd7083ee407ab)